# how to extract AT_EXECFN from a coredump file

Tags: linux, elf, coredump

I need to extract a value for [`AT_EXECFN`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html) from a coredump file. For those who don't know this value is part of [the auxiliary vector](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Auxiliary-Vector.html). It is really simple to get this value while in your running process, just use [`getauxval`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html), however I couldn't find any information on how to do it when you have an ELF coredump file. [I can find the `NT_AUXV` section of this file](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors.html), but I can't find out how to find an exact string where `AT_EXECFN` is pointing to. Say I found `AT_EXECFN` in the coredump. According to [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/uclibc-ng/latest/source/include/elf.h#L1064) I'm going to get a struct with ann address where the actual value is stored. My question is how do I find this address in the coredump file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
int main() { abort(); }

gcc -w -O2 t.c && ulimit -c unlimited && ./a.out
Aborted (core dumped)
```

First we can look with GDB:

```
gdb -q ./a.out core
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in ./a.out)
[New LWP 86]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) info auxv
33   AT_SYSINFO_EHDR      System-supplied DSO's ELF header 0x7ffd4037a000
16   AT_HWCAP             Machine-dependent CPU capability hints 0x178bfbff
...
31   AT_EXECFN            File name of executable        0x7ffd40374ff0 "./a.out"
15   AT_PLATFORM          String identifying platform    0x7ffd403739c9 "x86_64"
0    AT_NULL              End of vector                  0x0
```

This proves that the info is in fact present in the `core`, and also shows what values to expect.

The steps therefore are:

- read  / decode `NT_AUXV` note until you find an entry with `.a_type == AT_EXECFN` (    `31`). Find the pointer to string (`$addr`, here you would find `0x7ffd40374ff0`).

  Using `eu-readelf -n core` is helpful to verify that you are reading expected values. Here is the output:

```
  CORE                 320  AUXV
    SYSINFO_EHDR: 0x7ffd4037a000
    HWCAP: 0x178bfbff  <fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht>
...
    EXECFN: 0x7ffd40374ff0
    PLATFORM: 0x7ffd403739c9
    NULL
```

- iterate over all program headers with `.p_type == PT_LOAD` until you find one with `.p_vaddr <= $addr` and `$addr < .p_vaddr + .p_memsz` (that is, a `LOAD` segment which "covers" desired address). In above case, that's this entry:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
...
  LOAD           0x016000 0x00007ffd40354000 0x0000000000000000 0x021000 0x021000 RW  0x1000
...
```

- finally you can find location of the string in the `core` file at `.p_offset + $addr - .p_vaddr`. Using above numbers, we expect the string to be at offset `0x016000 + 0x7ffd40374ff0 - 0x00007ffd40354000 = 225264` bytes into the file.

  And we do find it there:

```
dd status=none bs=1 skip=225264 count=10 if=core | xxd -g1
00000000: 2e 2f 61 2e 6f 75 74 00 00 00                    ./a.out...
```

Comment: I can't figure out how did you determine the actual address of the path, in other words how did you figure out `.p_offset + $addr - .p_vaddr`? I've been reading documentation and and can't understand how did you come up with the formula.

Comment: @flashburn Sorry I don't understand the question: all the numbers I used: `EXECFN == 0x7ffd40374ff0`, `.p_offset == 0x016000` and `.p_vaddr == 0x00007ffd40354000` are visible in the answer.

Comment: Never mind.  I think I got it. It took me sometime to figure out how exactly you calculated the path address, but that I mean `.p_offset + $addr - .p_vaddr`. What I couldn't understand is why this formula works, but then I go figured it out. Thanks for helping out with this, I really appreciate it.